# ASP.NET MVC Empty Select when Fill a Select/Option from Json with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, json

Needed help here

This is my Model

```
public class SelectOption
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Method

```
public JsonResult GetJson()
{
    var list = new List<SelectOption>
                   {
                       new SelectOption { Value = "1", Text = "Aron" },
                       new SelectOption { Value = "2", Text = "Bob" },
                       new SelectOption { Value = "3", Text = "Charlie" },
                       new SelectOption { Value = "4", Text = "David" }
                   };
    return Json(list);
}
```

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("/Json/GetJson", null, function(data) {
            $("#MyList").addItems(data);
        });
    });

    $.fn.addItems = function(data) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var list = this;
            $.each(data, function(index, itemData) {
                var option = new Option(itemData.Text, itemData.Value);
                list.add(option);
            });
        });
    };

    $("#MyList").change(function() {
        alert('you selected ' + $(this).val());
    });

</script>
```

The above code doesnt have any error it's just that when everything is loaded, the Select/Dropdownlist will have 4 Empty Values, meaning that I can click on the DDL and there's 4 values, however it is empty string for all fours.

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to implement:

1. Sample Index View and Complete JQuery:

> ```
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
> }
>
> <h2>Index</h2>
>
>
> <select id="MyList">
>
> </select>
> <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>
>  $(function () {
>
>         LoadList();
>
>     });
>
> function LoadList() {
>
>         var procemessage = "<option value=''> Please wait...</option>";
>
>         $("#MyList").html(procemessage).show();
>
>
>         $.ajax(
>
>                    {
>                        url: "@Url.Action("GetJson", "Test")" ,
>                     type: "GET",
>
>                     success: function (data) {
>
>                     var markup = "<option value=''>-Select Option-</option>";
>
>                     for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
>
>                     markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" +
>                         data[x].Text + "</option>";
>
>                     }
>
>                     $("#MyList").html(markup).show();
>
>                     },
>
>                     error: function (reponse) {
>                     alert("error : " + reponse);
>                     }
>
>                     });
>
>                     }
>
> </script>
> ```

2. Controller:

   using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.Mvc;

   ```
   namespace stackoverflow.Controllers
   {
       public class TestController : Controller
       {
           // GET: Test
           public ActionResult Index()
           {
               return View();
           }


           [HttpGet]
           public JsonResult GetJson()
           {
               var list = new List<SelectOption>
                      {
                          new SelectOption { Value = "1", Text = "Aron" },
                          new SelectOption { Value = "2", Text = "Bob" },
                          new SelectOption { Value = "3", Text = "Charlie" },
                          new SelectOption { Value = "4", Text = "David" }
                      };

               return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Select Option Model:

   public class SelectOption
       {
          public string Text { get;  set; }
          public string Value { get;  set; }
       }

Comment: Thank you, but the value is 'Undefined', any idea why?

Comment: does it throw an error? does your dropdown load with undefined?

Comment: Thanks for your help. No error, the dropdown load with undefined

Comment: Ok i just tried and it work. I'll updated my response to include the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!